# How to determine which network interface VPN is connecting through?

Tags: 16.04, networking, openvpn

I help manage several remote systems that automatically connect to our VPN server when they boot using openvpn. At some of the sites, they connect to both the eth0 and wlan0 network interfaces but I do not know how to tell which interface the tun0 interface is being routed through. Any advice on how to determine this? I don't want to remotely disable one or the other interface to check as I could lose my ability to log back and re-enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

- `netstat -r` will provide you with a breakdown of your network connections and the gateways.  In most cases the one with the gateway `0.0.0.0` is likely the device through which the VPN will be active.
- `sudo netwatch -e tun0 -nt` will also provide useful information for monitoring device behavior. You could attempt to use telnet to send a quick message and monitor the `eth0` and `wlan0` using `netwatch` and see which sends the text in an encrypted format.
- last resort: list devices using `nmcli c`. Get the long device `{UUID#}` from the list then turn one off using `nmcli c down {UUID#}` and see which one breaks your VPN tunnel. Restore with `nmcli c up {UUID#}` You could use `chron` to automatically reissue the `nmcli c up {UUID#}` or `restart` to ensure it comes back up after a given period--provided the VPN is setup to automatically reconnect to the interface.

Best Luck!

Comment: Another option would be to use `tcpflow -i tun0 -c` and have it output some packets to the console then compare with packets from `tcpflow -i eth0 -c`.  You will see similar packet header addresses if you're using one vs the other.